# Get system time zone from NSTimeZone in "GMT 5:30" NSString format

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nstimezone

I'm a bit new to objective C.
I am trying to get system time zone in string format. I need only "**GMT 5:30**" in my string .

```
_devTimezone = (NSString*)[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get date description as string and then get required substring as

```
NSString *myDate = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
myDate=[myDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(26, 9)];
NSLog(@"%@",myDate);
```

u would get GMT+05:30 in log.

****EDITED****

if u are not sure what is index 
you can set date format and then access the index

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Wed, 14 Oct 2015 12:53:58 +0000";

 // Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, d LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSString *myDate = [date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
myDate=[myDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(26, 9)]; 
NSLog(@"%@",myDate);
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Surely  `descriptionWithLocale`  does not always return a string where the time zone is at offset 26?

Comment: I had answered according to the question. Can you let me know in which case time zone is not at offset at 26. I would surely find a solution to that.

Comment: before accessing the index i have set its format as above. This would make sure that starting index is 26.Now I hope it would work fine.

Comment: you are welcome chetan.. Kindly upvote the answer  if it worked for you.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NSTimeZone` method `secondsFromGMT` to obtain the offset as an `NSInteger` value and then format how you wish using the `NSString` method `stringWithFormat` and basic arithmetic to divide the integer value into hours and minutes.

Sample code:

```
- (NSString *) getTimeZoneOffset:(NSTimeZone *)timezone
{
   NSInteger minutesFromGMT = timezone.secondsFromGMT / 60; 

   // handle negative offsets
   char sign;
   if (minutesFromGMT < 0)
   {
      sign = '-';
      minutesFromGMT = -minutesFromGMT; // make positive
   }
   else
      sign = '+';

   // split in hours and minutes
   NSInteger hoursFromGMT = minutesFromGMT / 60;
   minutesFromGMT %= 60;

   // format as string - making sure minutes is two digits with leading zero if needed
   // cast to int is OK as no value will be greater than 59!
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GMT%c%d:%02d", sign, (int)hoursFromGMT, (int)minutesFromGMT];
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

//set timezone to GMT 5:30.
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSLog(@"User's current time %@",currentTime);
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: it gives current time.. not the desired output format "GMT:5:30"... thnaks anyway!! :)

Comment: see updated answer. It gives date in string format with GMT 5:30 timezone.